If $x=\frac{0.7y}{(1-y)(1-z)}-\frac{z}{1-z}$, $y_1>y_2$ and $z_1<z_2$, can anything said about relationship between $x_1$ and $x_2$
I have the equation $x=\frac{0.7y}{(1-y)(1-z)}-\frac{z}{1-z}$. Now assume that  $y_1>y_2$ and $z_1<z_2$. I want to check whether there any relationship between $x_1$ and $x_2$. Note that $0<x,y,z<1$.
I was trying to give an estimation for $x$ in terms of $y$ or $x$ alone. We have,
$$\frac{z}{1-z}<\frac{0.7y}{(1-y)(1-z)}<\frac{1}{1-z}$$
$$z<\frac{0.7y}{(1-y)}<1$$
It implies increase in $z$ gives increase in $y$? Does that give any contradiction?
Thank you !

Dependency on $y$ (keep $z$ fixed): for all $0 \le z \le 1$, $x$ is rising with $y$.
Dependency on $z$ (keep $y$ fixed): for $0 \le y \le \frac{10}{17}$, $x$ is falling  with $z$. Conversely, for $\frac{10}{17}\le y \le 1$, $x$ is rising with $z$.
Combining the two, you have a clear situation for  $0 \le y \le \frac{10}{17}$:
$x$ is rising with $y$ and falling  with $z$.  Hence, for  $y_1>y_2$ ($y$ falling) and $z_1<z_2$ ($z$ rising) you have that $x$ is falling, hence $x_1 > x_2$.
For $\frac{10}{17}\le y \le 1$, you always (no matter which $z$) have $x > 1$ which is excluded in your question.  So we are done.  But it is nevertheless illuminating to see what happens: no clear tendency for $x$ exists since the two effects of change with $y$ and $z$ can cancel. E.g. for $\frac{10}{17} < y < \frac{20}{27}$ and fixed $x=2$, you get $z = \frac{27 y-20}{10 (y-1)}$, so you have a trajectory where  $z$  rises as $y$ falls (exactly as your question puts it), but $x$ does not change.
So depending on the direction in the  $y$-$z$-plane, you will find both  $x_1 < x_2$ and $x_1 > x_2$.
